# python: replace strings in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary and I would like to replace all the strings in the lists that have a space followed by numbers (`vlc 2.2`, `ado 3.4` and `ultr 3.1`) just with their name, i.e. `vlc`, `ado` and `ultr`. Here is the input dictionary:

```
input = {'cl1': {'to_do': ['ab',
'dir8',
'cop',
'vlc 2.2.2.0',
'7zi',
'7zi',
'ado 3.4']},
'cl2': {'to_do': ['ultr 3.1', 'ab']}}
```

This should be the output:

```
result = {'cl1': {'to_do': ['ab',
'dir8',
'cop',
'vlc',
'7zi',
'7zi',
'ado']},
'cl2': {'to_do': ['ultr', 'ab']}}
```

I am trying something like:

```
for k in input:
    for e in input[k]['to_do']:
        input[k]['to_do'] = e.replace(e, e.split()[0])
```

Getting the wrong output:

```
{'cl1': {'to_do': 'ado'}, 'cl2': {'to_do': 'ab'}}
```

I don't fully understand where is the mistake. Any help? Thank you

Comment: Will there be strings with spaces that are _not_ followed by numbers, e.g. `ab cd`, and do you want to keep the latter part in this case?

Comment: @tobias_k The strings with a space will be only followed by numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this :

```
input[k]['to_do'] = e.replace(e, e.split()[0])
```

You replace the initial arrays (`['ultr 3.1', 'ab']` and `['ab', 'dir8', 'cop', 'vlc 2.2.2.0', '7zi', '7zi', 'ado 3.4']`) by a **single value** (the last one processed in your loop).

You just have to replace the inner loop by this single line to make it work :

```
input[k]['to_do'] = [e.split()[0] for e in input[k]['to_do']]
```

The correct result is given :

```
 {'cl2': {'to_do': ['ultr', 'ab']},
  'cl1': {'to_do': ['ab', 'dir8', 'cop', 'vlc', '7zi', '7zi', 'ado']}}
```

Comment: "You just have to replace the line above" In fact, you should replace _the entire inner loop_ with that line, not just the assignment within the loop.

Answer (score 5):

An even more generic way to do this would be to create a recursive method, that calls itself again:

```py
def recursive_split(input, search):
    # check whether it's a dict, list, tuple, or scalar
    if isinstance(input, dict):
        items = input.items()
    elif isinstance(input, (list, tuple)):
        items = enumerate(input)
    else:
        # just a value, split and return
        return str(input).split(search)[0]

    # now call ourself for every value and replace in the input
    for key, value in items:
        input[key] = recursive_split(value, search)
    return input
```

Please note, that this approach uses in-place replacement, but could easily be converted to return a new dictionary instead. This should cover any structure containing any type of values, that can be transformed into strings. In your case you would use it as by simply calling:

```
d = recursive_split(d, " ")
```

Comment: my brain cannot proceed with the way to return a new dictionary instead. seems hard. since you cannot dynamically add square bracket into dictionary variable e.g dict[x][y][z][.. and so on] to change its variable

Comment: @lone_coder You just have to replace the `input` with a new dict. Use the `isinstance` checks before to determine whether you need a list or a dict, create a new one and then set the results on this new object instead of the original one in the for loop. Note, that for a list, you might need to use the `append` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work if you want to strip anything following a space within the `to_do` lists. This seemed implied by your current implementation, but if you want digits only, you'll need to use a regex.

**Python 2**:

```
d = {
    'cl1': {
        'to_do': [
            'ab',
            'dir8',
            'cop',
            'vlc 2.2.2.0',
            '7zi',
            '7zi',
            'ado 3.4'
        ]
    },
    'cl2': {
        'to_do': [
            'ultr 3.1',
            'ab'
        ]
    }
}

for inner_dict in d.itervalues():
    inner_dict['to_do'] = [x.split()[0] for x in inner_dict['to_do']]

print d  # {'cl1': {'to_do': ['ab', 'dir8', 'cop', 'vlc', '7zi', '7zi', 'ado']}, 'cl2': {'to_do': ['ultr', 'ab']}}
```

**Python 3** (assume the same `d`):

```
for inner_dict in d.values():
    inner_dict['to_do'] = [x.split()[0] for x in inner_dict['to_do']]

print(d)
```

Comment: its appear to be a key error. since you directly call the "to_do" key without its parent key "cl1"